# I get a crash when i use my app. And i can't make it to reproduce. It is a SEGV_ACCERR error

Tags: ios, objective-c

There is my crash descripiton:

#0 Thread
SIGSEGV

SEGV_ACCERR

0 libobjc.A.dylib   objc_msgSend + 28

1 CoreLocation  CLClientGetCapabilities + 35548

2 CoreLocation  CLClientGetCapabilities + 33812

3 CoreLocation  CLClientInvalidate + 1000

4 CoreFoundation    **_CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 20

5 CoreFoundation    ___CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 288

6 CoreFoundation    ___CFRunLoopRun + 728

7 CoreFoundation    CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424

8 GraphicsServices  GSEventRunModal + 100

9 UIKit UIApplicationMain + 208

10 iSmartLBS    main (main.m:15)

11 libdyld.dylib    _start + 4

I open the organizer on Xcode just now, and i find more information:

{
  "SourceLine" : 1865,
  "SourceFile" : "CLLocationManager.m",
  "UserData" : {
    "Resolved" : false,
    "Name" : "CoreLocation: -[CLLocationManager onClientEventLocation:forceMapMatching:type:] + 1060",
    "Description" : ""
  },
  "DefaultName" : "CoreLocation: -[CLLocationManager onClientEventLocation:forceMapMatching:type:] + 1060"
}

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)

Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:

Thread 0 Crashed:

0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000183a98150 objc_msgSend + 16

1   CoreLocation                    0x000000018d2a6734 -[CLLocationManager onClientEventLocation:forceMapMatching:type:] + 1060 (CLLocationManager.m:1865)

2   CoreLocation                    0x000000018d2a606c -[CLLocationManager onClientEvent:supportInfo:] + 1000 (CLLocationManager.m:1660)

3   CoreLocation                    0x000000018d299278 ___Z22CLClientInvokeCallbackP10__CLClient13CLClientEventP11objc_object_block_invoke + 140 (CLClient.mm:763)

4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184fd130c **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 20 (CFRunLoop.c:1818)

5   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184fd0b28 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 288 (CFRunLoop.c:1855)

6   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184fce9bc __CFRunLoopRun + 764 (CFRunLoop.c:2823)

7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184efeda4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424 (CFRunLoop.c:3113)

8   GraphicsServices                0x0000000186968074 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)

9   UIKit                           0x000000018b1b9058 UIApplicationMain + 208 (UIApplication.m:4089)

10  iSmartLBS                       0x0000000100c3432c 0x10008c000 + 12223276

11  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000183f0d59c start + 4

Thread 1 name:

Thread 1:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183fff224 mach_msg_trap + 8

1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183fff09c mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)

2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184fd0e90 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192 (CFRunLoop.c:2527)

3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184fceae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1060 (CFRunLoop.c:2870)

4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184efeda4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424 (CFRunLoop.c:3113)

5   Foundation                      0x0000000185a18d74 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304 (NSRunLoop.m:367)

6   Foundation                      0x0000000185a39b44 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96 (NSRunLoop.m:411)

7   UIKit                           0x000000018bb436a8 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136 (UIEventFetcher.m:313)

8   Foundation                      0x0000000185b162d8 **NSThread__start** + 996 (NSThread.m:1163)

9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001840e568c _pthread_body + 240 (pthread.c:697)

10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001840e559c _pthread_start + 284 (pthread.c:744)

11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001840e2cb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 2 name:

Thread 2:

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183fff224 mach_msg_trap + 8

1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183fff09c mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)

2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184fd0e90 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192 (CFRunLoop.c:2527)

3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184fceae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1060 (CFRunLoop.c:2870)

4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184efeda4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424 (CFRunLoop.c:3113)

5   AVFAudio                        0x000000019f242540 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 164 (GenericRunLoopThread.h:106)

6   AVFAudio                        0x000000019f268814 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 84

7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001840e568c _pthread_body + 240 (pthread.c:697)

8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001840e559c _pthread_start + 284 (pthread.c:744)

9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001840e2cb4 thread_start + 4

Answer (score 1):

The crash is caused SIGSEGV in objc_msgSend. This means you have tried to access invalid object address. This means there a some issue related to memory in app.

This problem mostly faced while you do delete or any operation  on UITableView

**Solution**

1. You can find using your Analyze of xcode and fix all warning that they displayed to you.
2. Also You can track this using enable zoombie and `Instrument` tool in xcode .

Comment: Is this crash about location?

Comment: yes if you are do enable zombie and run again in instrument tool with that steps where you app actually crashed then  it  will stop and display object which  caused crash.

Comment: Is it possible that multiple threads have access to the same attributes and cause this problem?

Comment: yes but your object deallocated before access then this error appeared .